# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager

Tags: java

First off, lets start by saying im quite a noob at this. Im trying to use a website java app but i keep getting this error. Not sure what it is.

Dont know if this helps:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-54" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2587)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2611)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldDate(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getLastModified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline.checkForUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.util.SecurityBaseline$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've also included this image of the error that im getting][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETiW2.png)

Thanks for all the help in advance